# passing null value to textbox which has decimal number

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2008-r2, .net-4.0

passing null value to textbox which has decimal number

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@P", SqlDbType.Decimal)).Value = decimal.Parse(TB_P.Text == null ? DBNull.Value : (object)TB_P.Text);//decimal.Parse(TB_P.Text);//
```

> The best overloaded method match for 'decimal.Parse(string)' has some
>   invalid arguments

Comment: If the textbox contains the value 0 do you want a null or just 0?

Comment: @Steve zero is good too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your test in this way

```
decimal.TryParse(TB_P.Text, out decimal result);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@P", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = (result == 0 ? (object)DBNull.Value : result);
```

but if 0 is a valid value to write then you need to be more verbose

```
object value;
if (!decimal.TryParse(TB_P.Text, out decimal result))
    value = DBNull.Value;
else
    value = result;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@P", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = value;
```

Also note that a TextBox.Text property is never null. It could be an empty string but not a null value as easily demonstrable with

```
TB_P.Text = null;
Console.WriteLine(TB_P.Text == null ? "Is null" : "Is not null");
```

Comment: I got around 10 `textbox` like this one declaring decimal variable `result` for each one not good idea am I right ? any work around with linq for example so it still in one line of code ?

Comment: You don't need to declare 10 result variables. You can just reuse the first one. Once you have set the Value of the parameter you can reuse the same variable.

Comment: Also, when parsing user input you really should always use the TryParse approach. If the user types something that is not a number you get a very costly exception

Comment: I am validating `textbox` input on leave event with `regexp` so user will not enter anything except numbers

Comment: Error `Invalid expression term 'decimal'`

Comment: Ah, I see now Visual-Studio-2013.... That version doesn't understand the inline declaration of the result variable inside the TryParse. You need to declare it before calling. _decimal result; decimal.TryParse(...., out result);_

Comment: but why when using `textbox` with string it will accept null string without any process? I understand from your comment that `textbox` will not be null but an empty string so decima.parase should convert that empty string to decimal string am I right ?

Comment: No an empty string is not parsable to a decimal. It will trigger the exception if you use Parse on it. You can see here https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,4012 in the source code of Control.Text what happens when you set the TextBox.Text property.